# composed filter() in python doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

As far as i understand, the following code should output `[['b']]`.
Instead, it outputs `[['a', 'exclude'], ['b']]`.

Is it a bug in python, or do I misunderstand something?

```py
lists_to_filter = [
    ['a', 'exclude'],
    ['b']
]
# notice that when 'exclude' is the last element, the code returns the expected result
for exclude_label in ['exclude', 'something']:
    lists_to_filter = (labels_list for labels_list in lists_to_filter if exclude_label not in labels_list)
    # notice that changing the line above to the commented line below (i.e. expanding the generator to a list) 
    # will make the code output the expected result, 
    # i.e. the issue is only when using filter on another filter, and not on a list
    # lists_to_filter = [labels_list for labels_list in lists_to_filter if exclude_label not in labels_list]
lists_to_filter = list(lists_to_filter)
print(lists_to_filter)
```

Comment: Check the indentation in the last, `lists_to_filter` is getting redefined inside the loop. That is why code is running when 'exclude' is the last element.
If you put `lists_to_filter = list(lists_to_filter)` and `print(lists_to_filter)` inside the loop, it should work

Comment: The indentation is intended -- the last 2 lines are just to output. The issue happens before them - when I do `filter(filter(something))` it doesn't give the same output as `filter(list(filter(something)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `lists_of_filter` is only iterated outside the loop. Outside the loop you have `exclude_label == 'something'`, that is why you get unexpected results. To check it you can put a line `exclude_label = 'exclude'`:

```
lists_to_filter = [
    ['a', 'exclude'],
    ['b']
]

for exclude_label in ['exclude', 'something']:
    lists_to_filter = (labels_list for labels_list in lists_to_filter if exclude_label not in labels_list)

exclude_label = 'exclude'
lists_to_filter = list(lists_to_filter)
print(lists_to_filter)  # [['b']]
```

The [doc for generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) says that "*Subsequent for clauses and any filter condition in the leftmost for clause cannot be evaluated in the enclosing scope as they may depend on the values obtained from the leftmost iterable.*". In your case the filter condition `if exclude_label ...` depends on a value obtained from `for exclude_label in ...` loop.

Comment: Nice catch! I did not know that variables in generators are evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 0):

because you multiple assign `lists_to_filter` in loop, so it will only return the last result. that is not include `'something'`, the last element in `['exclude', 'something']`

you can use `all` to achieve your goal:

```
lists_to_filter = [labels_list for labels_list in lists_to_filter if all(exclude_label not in labels_list for exclude_label in ['exclude', 'something'])]
```

or expand `all` logic:

```
    result = []

    for labels_list in lists_to_filter:
        exclude = False
        for exclude_label in ['exclude', 'something']:
            if exclude_label in labels_list:
                exclude = True
        if not exclude:
            result.append(labels_list)

    print(result)
```

or you can use `filter` according to your title:

```
lists_to_filter = list(filter(lambda x: all(exclude_label not in x for exclude_label in exclude_labels), lists_to_filter))
```

output:

```
[['b']]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: 1. this is a toy example and in fact my code is more complicated, so i will prefer something that does not require me to use all etc...

2. i do not understand why you say that multiple assignments in a loop won't work. for example, using `x=2; for i in range(2): x=x**2;` will return `16`
3. if you were correct, than changing the assigment from generator to a list would also keep the previous behaviour.

Comment: for the second point, the example should be `x = i**2`, so it is only keep the last i in result.

Comment: if the logic is complicate and you don't want to use `all`, you can expand the block, and implement the feature similiar to `all`, or ,you can use @John solution, use set intersection or something else

Comment: I have add a version with expand `all` loigc, is that you looking for? @tsvikas

Comment: about `x=x**2`, you can see, in your example, previous `x` will effect new `x`, so it transmit value in loop, but in your list comprehension is not.