# Generator set in loop being overwritten

Tags: python, pointers, iterator, generator

I'm trying to write a function to build a flattened tree of generators based on a list. So if I have a list of items, I want to start with an empty generator, and call a function on the first item and the empty generator, and call the function on the second item and the output of the first function call, and then call the function on the third item and the output of the second function call, and so on. **Importantly, I don't want to actually evaluate *anything* until `next` is called on the final generator!**

So, if the function we're calling on the list and generators is called `foo`, (and it outputs a generator too, obviously), and the list of items is `list`...

Right now, what I have is a prototype that looks like this:

```
>>> tree = iter([{}])
>>> tree = chain.from_iterable((foo(list[0], p) for p in tree))
>>> tree = chain.from_iterable((foo(list[1], p) for p in tree))
>>> tree = chain.from_iterable((foo(list[2], p) for p in tree))
>>> list(tree)
```

That actually works. It evaluates everything correctly and most importantly doesn't evaluate anything unnecessarily (the lines that begin with an integer are logs printed out when something is actually:

```
>>> next(tree)
Called on 0
Called on 1
Called on 2
Result A
>>> next(tree)
Called on 1
Called on 2
Result B
```

**UNFORTUNATELY**, when I try to use a  loop to get this to work on a `tail` with an arbitrary length:

```
tree = iter([{}])
for item in list:
    tree = chain.from_iterable((foo(item, p) for p in tree))
```

It doesn't work. Instead, the `tree` variable is set to the result of `foo` called on an *empty* possibility, as if it was the only thing evaluated! I have no idea what's happening, although I have a *hunch* that its because there is a pointer or something.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related (maybe): https://stackoverflow.com/q/55673872/9609843

Comment: Yeah that does seem to be related... What if surmise from that is that generator expressions in Python don't save their scope for the right part of the expression, they use the variables at execution time. I'm not sure how I'd fix that though, especially since saving the intermediate `tree`s didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The call for recursion is clear here:

```py
import itertools as it


def lazy_reduce(list_, tree_base, i=None):
  if i is None:
    i = len(list_)

  if i < 0:
    return iter(tree_base)

  return it.chain.from_iterable(
    foo(list_[i], p)
    for p in lazy_reduce(list_, tree_base, i - 1)
  )
```

Comment: The original version of this, before I tried using chain, was recursive. But I don't want to limit the amount of items by the stack size since this is for an interpreter that uses this system as its way of having multiple statements.

Comment: If that is the case, you could easily imitate recursion with a manually-managed stack and a `for` loop.

Comment: I already tried this by pushing each intermediate value onto a stack and having the next value depend on the previous one (by index not [-1] so subsiquent changes don't mess stuff up) and it didn't seem to work-- it did the exact same thing.

Comment: As it turns out, this is because they refer to the value of the surrounding scope, they don't take closures. So, if `i` was 3 when the generator was created but `9` when it finished, all the generators will use 9.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem with generator scope you can make a function that will have its own scope:

```
def add_item(tree, item):
    return chain.from_iterable((foo(item, p) for p in tree))

tree = iter([{}])
for item in list:
    tree = add_item(tree, item)
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid calling a function to do this though. Because then the amount of items is limited by the stack size. I'm trying to do this for a programming language that only has sequential execution through this algorithm so that would limit program size.